# Greek symbol for bit?

Tags: notation, terminology

Symbols / greek letters are used in mathematical notation for variables, functions etc. and commonly informs the reader that it is definied within a conventional accepted range. What is the most common symbol for a bit / two-state integer?

I found maybe the $\xi$ symbol can be used? or maybe something else is used.

For example $\xi\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ where $\xi$ can either be $0$ or $1$. $\xi \equiv 0 |1\pmod 2$

Question is; which symbol is commonly used for a two state variable?

Comment: So long as you define it, it doesn't really matter what symbol you use.  That being said, $\chi$ appears in several contexts as indicator variables / indicator functions / random variables such as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) and would have been my first choice outside of using $a,\alpha,x$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok. I like $\alpha$. I might just use that. And yeah, I could have added that the variable I need a greek letter for acts like a flag (on or off) etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is very common to use the letter y for binary variables.
y1, y2, y3 etc.

I don't think there is any Greek letter particularly used for this.